# Is Kirchhoff's scalar theory of diffraction mathematically inconsistent?

Tags: electromagnetism, diffraction, boundary-conditions, approximations, greens-functions

I've heard that [Kirchhoff's scalar diffraction theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_diffraction_formula) is mathematically inconsistent. Is this true? If so, where in the formulation does this inconsistency arise and are there ways to remedy it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Kirchhoff's scalar diffraction theory is mathematically inconsistent. The reason is as follows. Kirchhoff proved that any function $U$ satisfying the homogeneous wave equation $\nabla^2U+k^2U=0$ also satisfies the integral equation
$$U(\mathcal P)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\int_{\mathcal S} \left[U(\mathcal Q)\frac{\partial}{\partial n} \left(\frac{e^{\mathfrak j kr}}{r}\right)-\left(\frac{e^{\mathfrak j kr}}{r}\right)\frac{\partial U(\mathcal Q)}{\partial n}\right]ds(\mathcal Q) \tag{1}$$
In Eq (1) the point of observation is $\mathcal P$ at which the wave $U$ is calculated by integrating the function over the closed surface $\mathcal S$ that contains the point of observation. The $r$ is the distance between the points $\mathcal Q$ of the surface and $\mathcal P$.

This Eq. (1) is true for any reasonable smooth surface $\mathcal S$. It also holds if the surface is a half-plane while one extends a hemisphere to infinity.
This integral equation or rather identity expresses that given the solution and its normal derivative of the wave equation on a closed surface one can obtain the complete solution inside that surface. So far so good.

The *mathematical* problem starts when the formula is applied to a diffraction problem, say an opaque screen with a hole being illuminated by a plane or spherical wave. If the hole is several wavelengths across then it is reasonable to assume that inside the hole the wave does not change much and can be taken as given. But what about the shadow side of the opaque screen where the wave should be known so we can apply Eq (1)? A reasonable assumption would be that on the screen in the shadow side  we can set $U(\mathcal Q)=0$, but we still need to know the normal derivative of $U$.

We cannot just set that normal derivative to zero, there is no *physical* justification for that, and moreover, one cannot just arbitrarily set *both* boundary condition independently for the Helmholtz equation: at any surface point we can only prescribe one or the other, but not both. This is the mathematical inconsistency. Amazingly, despite the inconsistency and to the chagrin to all mathematicians it works very well in practice.
Yes, there are ways to fix the inconsistency but general consensus is that it is rarely worth it, Sommerfeld's fix is a good point of departure, see Born & Wolf Chapter 8.

Comment: Jackson (being Jackson) grapples a lot with the mathematical problems of scalar and vector diffraction theory in his book (in somewhat different ways in different editions).  I used to spend some time on these issues when teaching graduate E&M, but I eventually decided the time was better spent on other topics—because of what it says in the last two sentences of this answer.  The theory can be made more mathematically rigorous, but it is generally not useful in practice.

Comment: +1 Mathematical rigor is correlated with physical utility, but it is neither sufficient nor necessary.